# How to store sessions in firebase flutter app

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hello World I am new to Flutter and Firebase i am currently creating a Language learning app, i am confused as to how i can store a session in a database. For example

**First Scenario**

A user has chosen a language and has started learning, when the user has finished learning two chapters, how is the learning session going to be stored, so that later the user can resume from where he/she left it at

**Second Scenario**

A user has finished learning two chapters and has reviewed one chapter, how is the reviewing session going to be stored, so that later the user can resume from where he/she left it at

I would like to know which database model is suitable to use and whether there is a certain topic in databases i can specifically learn  to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option is not to use a database, but rather save the chapter numbers on the device as part of the persistent storage.

You can use this package called shared_preferences: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

It is relatively easy to learn and would fit the use case you described.